# React Native Algoritmic Challenge

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, react-native, genetic-algorithm

I have to design a project in React Native where I need to create a "wheel of fate" . This project should take from a list of 10 people, two of them (randomly) to complete a random day of support for each.

The rules of this task are the following:

- A person can do at most one half-day shift in a day.
- Each person should have completed one whole day of support in any 2 week period.
- A person cannot have half-day shifts on consecutive days.

My approach for this project was first of all creating a function that will get two random different people as following.

```
      var workers =require('./workers.json')
      const shuffled = workers.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    
    // Get sub-array of first n elements after shuffled
    let selected = shuffled.slice(0, 2);
```

Next, I tried to push each of this group of workers to someday but I kind of got stuck

I expect that my output will provide a table or a list which will respect the rules specified previously.

Comment: Just a list with each day and the shifts should do it

Comment: No, in a day, as I mentioned